# Netezza encryption and disk space utilization

Tags: encryption, netezza

Does encrypting data on Netezza using the SQL extension toolkit utilize more disk space?  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21672494

Answer (score 0):

Not that I’ve ever used that functionality, but I would expect that to be a VERY limited effect.
A comment:
I hope you will not use this functionality for ALL data. At least join keys and columns you plan to run WHERE clauses against should probably be omitted for performance reasons. Furthermore I fail to see what you try to accomplish by this? Make sure that the DBA cannot read your data? 
I suspect that will not work: your pg.log will contain the ‘password’....